# Somando arquivos de texto com python

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho uma serie de arquivos em .txt e gostaria de soma-los / juntar todos num só usando um script em python.

algo como:

```
#Abre o arquivo que receberá a soma de todos os outros
arq.open("redação.txt", "w")

#escreve todas as linhas de cada arquivo por vez (Aqui está meu problema!)
arq.write(arq=(texto1.txt + texto2.txt + texto3.txt + texto4.txt + texto5.txt))

#Fecha o arquivo
arq.close
```

já pesquisei sobre soma de arquivos e textos em python, mas não achei nada especificamente desta forma

Comment: Mais fácil fazer da linha de comando. Linux:`cat aqr1 arq2 arq3 > destino` .Windows:`type aqr1 arq2 arq3 > destino` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você abre um arquivo, é retornado um gerador referente ao arquivo. Você pode passá-lo diretamente ao método `writelines` para escrever seu conteúdo no arquivo final. Veja o exemplo:

```
# Abre o arquivo redacao.txt para escrita:
with open("redacao.txt", "w") as file:

    # Percorre a lista de arquivos a serem lidos:
    for temp in ["texto1.txt", "texto2.txt", "texto3.txt"]:

        # Abre cada arquivo para leitura:
        with open(temp, "r") as t:

            # Escreve no arquivo o conteúdo:
            file.writelines(t)
```

Considerando os arquivos:

**texto1.txt**

```
a1
a2
a3
```

**texto2.txt**

```
b1
b2
b3
```

**texto3.txt**

```
c1
c2
c3
```

O arquivo **redacao.txt** será:

```
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
c1
c2
c3
```

Comment: Testado e aprovado.

Answer (score 4):

Nao sei se entendi direito sua pergunta, você quer abrir varios arquivos e juntar todos em 1 so?

Se for isso, tente o seguinte:

```
arq = open("resultado.txt", "w") 
arq1 = open("texto1.txt", "r")
arq2 = open("texto2.txt", "r")
arq.write(arq1.read()+arq2.read())
arq.close()
```

Se nao for isso que vc queria, tente explicitar mais a duvida.

Comment: Gabriel, funcionou.
A resposta do Anderson veio um pouco depois mas presumi que ficou um pouco mais bem elaborada.

Comment: sim, que bom que conseguiu resolver o problema

Answer (score 1):

Não gosto de pedir interativamente nomes de ficheiros, ou de estes ficarem fixos; prefiro a criação de scripts que recebem parâmetros via linha de comando. Nesse sentido recomendo o módulo fileinput. Seja `cat.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import fileinput
for linha in fileinput.input():
   print(linha.strip())
```

Deste modo a script funciona como um comando normal Unix, e na linha de comando podemos dar zero (stdin, pipes) ou mais ficheiros a processar.

Podemos agora usar `cat.py` com qualquer número de ficheiros.

```
$ cat.py  texto*.txt > redação.txt
```